# python apply lambda function

Tags: python, lambda, aggregate

I have a use-case where I need to apply an function argument on another argument which is typically a list. Example I might need to apply min on a list, max on a list or sum on a list.

```
def calc_df_query(select_col, agg_func, where_col, mn, mx):
    tmp = globals().get('data')[select_col][globals().get('data')[where_col].between(mn, mx, inclusive=True)]
    agg_method = lambda col,agg: agg(col)
    return (agg_method(tmp, agg_func))
```

As a result of the last return statement I am getting an error "str object is not callable". Any help to do this trick is appreciated.

Comment: It looks as though agg_method is coming back as a string which you then are trying to use as a function with agg_method(). Hence the error str object is not callable

Comment: what are you expecting `agg_func` to be? It is a `str`, and you can't call a string. The error message is pretty clear. This has nothing to do with your `lambda` as far as I can tell. I've got to say, though, this is a pretty weird way to use a lambda, why don'y you just `return agg_func(tmp)`? Why are you wrapping this in a `lambda` at all? It constributes nothing, since you immediately apply it and discard it...

Comment: agg_func indeed is a str (could have the values "mean", "sum", "max", "min"). And obviously that's the problem, because when I run gg_method(tmp, min), it works. How do I convert a string like "min" to the actual min function ?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use a dictionary to map strings to pandas.DataFrame functions

```
dispatcher={'min':pd.DataFrame.min, 'max':pd.DataFrame.max, 'sum': pd.DataFrame.sum, 'mean': pd.DataFrame.mean}
```

and then the usage:

```
def calc_df_query(select_col, agg_func, where_col, mn, mx):
    tmp = globals().get('data')[select_col][globals().get('data')[where_col].between(mn, mx, inclusive=True)]
    agg_method = lambda col, agg: agg(col)
    return (agg_method(tmp, dispatcher.get(agg_func)))
```

thanks for the tips